# Is there a way to ignore some entity properties when calling EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx

Tags: entity-framework-5, breeze

I am specifically using breezejs and the server code for breeze js converts the dbcontext into a form which is useable on the clientside using `EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx`. There are many properties which I have added `JsonIgnore` attributes to so that they don't get passed to the client side. However, the metadata that is generated (and passed to the clientside) from `EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx` still has those properties. Is there any additional attribute that I can add to those properties that I want ignored so that they are ignored by `EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx`? Or, would I need to make a separate method so as not to have any other unintended side effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sub-class your `DbContext` with a more restrictive variant that you use solely for metadata generation. You can continue to use your base context for persistence purposes.

The DocCode sample illustrates this technique with its [`NorthwindMetadataContext`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.DataAccess.EF/NorthwindMetadataContext.cs) which hides the `UserSessionId` property from the metadata.

It's just a few extra lines of code that do the trick.

```
public class NorthwindMetadataContext : NorthwindContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Hide from clients
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Ignore(t => t.CustomerID_OLD);

        // Ignore UserSessionId in metadata (but keep it in base DbContext)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Ignore(t => t.UserSessionId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Ignore(t => t.UserSessionId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().Ignore(t => t.UserSessionId);
        // ... more of the same ...
    }
}
```

The Web API controller delegates to the [`NorthwindRepository`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.DataAccess.EF/NorthwindRepository.cs) where you'll see that the `Metadata` property gets metadata from the `NorthwindMetadataContext` while the other repository members reference an `EFContextProvider` for the full `NorthwindContext`.

```
public class NorthwindRepository
{
    public NorthwindRepository()
    {
        _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<NorthwindContext>();
    }

    public string Metadata
    {
        get
        {
            // Returns metadata from a dedicated DbContext that is different from
            // the DbContext used for other operations
            // See NorthwindMetadataContext for more about the scenario behind this.
            var metaContextProvider = new EFContextProvider<NorthwindMetadataContext>();
            return metaContextProvider.Metadata();
        }
    }

    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        PrepareSaveGuard();
        return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }

    public IQueryable<Category> Categories {
      get { return Context.Categories; }
    }
    // ... more members ...
}
```

Pretty clever, eh?

Just remember that the `UserSessionId` is still on the server-side class model and could be set by a rogue client's `saveChanges` requests.  DocCode guards against that risk in its `SaveChanges` validation processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can sub-class your `DbContext` with a more restrictive variant that you use solely for metadata generation. You can continue to use your base context for persistence purposes.

The DocCode sample illustrates this technique with its [`NorthwindMetadataContext`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.DataAccess.EF/NorthwindMetadataContext.cs) which hides the `UserSessionId` property from the metadata.

It's just a few extra lines of code that do the trick.

The Web API controller delegates to the [`NorthwindRepository`](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js.samples/blob/master/net/DocCode/DocCode.DataAccess.EF/NorthwindRepository.cs) where you'll see that the `Metadata` property gets metadata from the `NorthwindMetadataContext` while the other repository members reference an `EFContextProvider` for the full `NorthwindContext`.

Pretty clever, eh?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [NotMapped] attribute on a property, then it should be ignored by the EDMX process.

Comment: yeah, but that has side effects of making the field not mapped, which I don't want. I just don't want them transfered to the client, but I don't want to make dtos for all of the vos either.